# wpa_supplicant is configured but wpa_state remains SCANNING and connection to the wifi server isn't established

Tags: linux, networking, wifi, wpa-supplicant

I'm having trouble trying to connect to local wifi through setting up wpa_supplicant.

Following is what I ran  to configure the supplicant:

```
modprobe <wifi-driver>
iw dev wlan0 set type station
ifconfig wlan0 up
wpa_supplicant -i wlan0 -D nl80211 -c /etc/misc/wifi/wpa_supplicant.conf

wpa_cli -i wlan0 status   // returns "wpa_state=SCANNING"
```

wpa_supplicant.conf is:

```
ctrl_interface=/var/run/wpa_supplicant

network={
#WPA-PSK
        ssid=<ssid>
        proto=WPA
        key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
        pairwise=TKIP CCMP
        group=TKIP CCMP
        psk=<pwd>
}
```

When I go into an interactive mode, I see

```
<3>CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-RESULTS
<3>WPS-AP-AVAILABLE
<3>CTRL-EVENT-NETWORK-NOT-FOUND
```

Is there anything that I should be concerned with other than incorrect SSID and PWD?

Answer (score 0):

With `proto=WPA` you are trying to use the first (insecure) version of the WPA security protocol only. Modern access points will most likely require WPA2 at minimum, and might even support WPA3.

Set `proto=RSN` to accept both WPA2 and WPA3 but not WPA(1).

Comment: I tried it but that didn't solve the issue